# Git Credential Manager Not Found on WSL2

Tags: git, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, git-credential-manager

## Error Message

```bash
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe get: 1: /mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe: not found
```

## Problem Story

I found this problem then git ask me for a username and password to authenticate to GitHub whenever I'm doing git activity with GitHub remote repository from my local WSL2 environment.

It is very annoying to do this every time, then I search and follow several tutorials I can find on the internet, but everything just led me to the same problem again, these tutorial is not solving my problem at all.

Every tutorial tells me that I should add the GCM directory in the Windows environment for the git in the WSL2 environment. Theoretically, it should solve my problem, but it is not.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Solution

If there is no `git-credential-core.exe` in your git folder, then use it instead of the `git-credential-wincred.exe`. No `-core` executable file exists, so I use the `-wincred` file.

Execute this command on WSL2 (use the `-core` rather than `-wincred` if it exists):

```bash
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-core.exe"
```

**only if the above command ❌ fails or does not solve the problem,** change to `-wincred`

```bash
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-wincred.exe"
```

## Explanation

I think `git-credential-manager-core.exe` has already been renamed `git-credential-wincred.exe`, but many tutorials on the internet are already deprecated because they gave us the old name of this executable file. This is my biggest problem because following any tutorial makes me find the same error over time.

Comment: this have not worked for me. Using "-wincred" throws some error I have unfortunatelly not saved. It needs to be the "-core" one, this works like a charm (the other answer).

Comment: @JanVilimek you should check your git version first, in the newer version it uses -wincred. in the older version it uses -core

Comment: I am using 2.37.0 and the error was probably `<3>init: (30629) ERROR: UtilConnectToInteropServer:307: connect failed 2
` ... as now I am getting the same error even while using the -core version :/

UPDATE: the error occurs only in vscode...when running from a console (WSL/bash), its working...

Comment: @JanVilimek you can ask a new question for it, and please provide the detail, like whether the vscode terminal is using the gitcred from windows or not.

Comment: thank you ! It works for me , feels painful to use linux with window :(

Comment: @VinceNguyen Yeah, It's a lot of painful to use WSL2, in my experience I would recommend any of my friend to use native windows instead of using WSL2, or just get a macOS or native Linux installed. Just.. don't half hearted when we do something, do it with all of our hand.

Answer (score 13):

I faced a similar issue on WSL2 with Windows 10 when I upgraded Git for Windows to one of the recent versions (2.37.0 I think). This is because the git-credential-manager-core.exe has been moved to a different folder.

**Solution:**

To fix this issue, run the following command from your bash command line:

`git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager-core.exe"`

**Note:** If you have Git installed in a different drive/folder - update the path accordingly.

Comment: nice! that's the correct path. Thanks!

Comment: `git-credential-manager-core.exe` has been renamed to `git-credential-manager.exe` (no `-core`)

Comment: where is git-credential-manager.exe? I don't have that exe, I just have git-credential-store and git-credential-wincred

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem using wsl2 with git version 2.34.1 installed both on windows and wsl and turns out they have moved the git-credential-manager-core.exe file... use this command ...

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very frustrating that configuring git on WSL2 seems to be constantly evolving and you need to sift through so many obsolete solutions before stumbling upon the one that works. Each time my token has expired, I was not able to simply replace it with a new one.

Make sure your Git for Windows and Git in WSL2 are the same version.

For me, authenticating with a GitHub personal access token was solved by:

```
[credential]
helper = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe
credentialStore = wincred
```

Note: `git-credential-manager.exe`. Not `git-credential-manager-core.exe` (which is obsolete). Not a 32-bit version. Not `git-credential-wincred.exe`.

Note 2: I saw some answers with: `helper =` . This did not work for me. I had to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I did was identify the file:  C:/Users/name.user/.gitconfig

I open it with a text edit and did the following

```
--DELETE

[credential]
    helper = wincred
    helper = 
    helper = C:/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe
-------

--Change correct repo
[credential "https://xyz.azure.com"]
------
Result:
[user]
    name = 'name.user'
    email = 'name.user@email.mx'
[credential https://myrepo.azure.com"]
    useHttpPath = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issues as well, with WSL 2 and fresh install of Git for Windows 2.38.1.

Turned out the path I got from the tutorials was wrong for me. In my case the correct command was:

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-credential-wincred.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful for me in solving it.
https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/rename.md

I edited my

> ~/.config

This was the OLD

> helper = /mnt/c/Program\Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager-core.exe

This is the NEW

> helper =
>
> helper = /mnt/c/Program\
> Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe

There is a blank helper on purpose. See the link above.